# VB script to automate importing sharepoint list data to excel

Tags: list, custom-list, excel, script, vba

I need to automate pulling data from SharePoint list data to excel through writing a VB Script (not VBA).

How can I import data directly from a SharePoint List into Excel using VB script?

Currently, I am manually exporting to an Excel file. I would like to eliminate that manual step.

I've searched online but am not coming up with any good results. Any ideas where I can start?

Thanks